# Command-line XML validator for Windows

Tags: windows, xml, validation, command-line, xsd

I've always found validation against a schema to be an invaluable ward against thinkos and would like to incorporate validation checks as part of a project where I frequently need to hand-write XML files a few hundred lines in length.  My text editor has a fairly nice CLI integration feature, so I'm looking for a command-line validator.

When I didn't find any clear winners via Google, I poked around here and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124865/xml-schema-validation-tool), but none of the tools suggested there quite fit my needs:

- [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) (via cygwin) — does not report line numbers; I have no idea *where* my errors are!
- [msxml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28VS.85%29.aspx) — cannot be run from the command line?
- [xerces-c](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) — seems to require a copy of Visual C?
- [xerces2-j](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) — cannot be run from the command line?
- [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) — insufficient XSD support*

(*The schema I'm validating against uses substitution groups — inappropriately, but it's external to the project, so I can't change it — which causes `xmlstarlet` to choke even on valid files.)

Normally, this is the point in solving a problem at which I'd give up on looking for an existing solution and reach for the Python-hammer, but Python's XML support is notoriously… well… actually, let's just leave it at "notorious".

So I'm back to looking for a pre-existing tool.  My requirements are pretty simple:

- runs on Win32 (Windows XP SP3, specifically)
- command-line; my editor can work with just about any combination of stdin/-out/-err, arguments, temp files, etc.
- reasonably complete XSD support (particularly namespaces and substitution groups)
- reports the line number where the error occurred!

Does such a tool exist?  I'd prefer not to have to install Visual Studio and friends (too bloated, IMO), but I do already have both Cygwin and Python installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first option, xmllint (libxml2), does give line numbers for errors in the xml (and also in the xsd). You probably just need a later version.  I just confirmed both using my copy, which is:

```
>  xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20627
```

Example output:

```
invalidXml.xml:4: element c: Schemas validity error : Element 'c': This element is not expected. Expected is ( b ).
invalidXml.xml fails to validate
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<invalidXmlEg>
  <a/>
<!--  <b></b> -->
  <c/>
</invalidXmlEg>
```

Where the xsd is:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="invalidXmlEg">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

NOTE: I have noticed that xmllint will accept elements names that it shouldn't (e.g. "`<invalidXml.xsd>`"), but this doesn't seem to affect your task.

*EDIT* adding the "compiled with" part of the version:

```
 compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader
 Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy
 C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X
 Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron
 Modules Debug Zlib
```

Comment: Interesting! The version I'm using is 20703, which produces "`Element 'c': This element is not expected. Expected is ( b ).`" (nearly identical, but lacks line number). I'll have to see if I can dig up and older version.

Comment: Seems a backward step... I wonder if they added an option, for whether line numbers are included or not?  Might be worth checking the docs (maybe --verbose).  Or... maybe it's to do with what has been compiled in?  I didn't include that, but I'll add it (also I'm running on linux, which shouldn't make any difference): it's    compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib

Comment: Looks like the version of `libxml` in Cygwin is compiled with the same options, and there doesn't seem to be any `--verbose`-like option. I ended up grabbing the Win32 binaries for 2.6.27 from the official site and it works just fine. A backwards step, indeed. :-)

Answer (score 3):

As 13ren stated above, libxml's xmllint does report line numbers - perhaps you have a version issue. You might find it useful to grab native (non cygwin) versions of the libxml/libxslt tools from http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html

You might also want to take a look at msv from [Sun](https://msv.dev.java.net/). It isn't a full implementation of XSD but might do the job (I use it for RelaxNG validation generally)

Comment: The linked windows binaries are unfortunately completely outdated and  don't seem to work properly on modern Windows versions (at least I couldn't get the xmllint to produce useful output on my Windows 10). Do you know about up-to-date binaries somewhere? Otherwise it's back to building it on one's own I guess, done that, and it's simple enough with CMake

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536168/is-xmllint-for-windows-in-active-development) might be useful

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Windows Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) with [PowerShell Community eXtensions](http://www.codeplex.com/Pscx). PSCX has the Test-Xml cmdlet which has the following `Get-Help` detailed description:

> Tests for well formedness and optionally validates against XML Schema.  It doesn't handle specifying the targetName
>   space.  To see validation error messages, specify the -Verbose flag.

I do not know if it reports the errors with linenumbers but 3 out 4 isn't bad.

Answer (score 1):

You might try one of the [Visual Studio 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express) editions. There's much better XML support now, including validation, of course, but also XML Intellisense, XML snippets, and an XML Schema view.

Comment: I doubt that devenv can validate XML files on the commandline.

Comment: I didn't suggest it could. I'm suggesting the UI experience may be sufficiently good to change how you work with XML files.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to comment, but the latest version of xmllint (20708) Windows port from Igor Zlatkovic is giving line numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Xerces-J comes with a sample application, [jaxp.SourceValidator](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/samples-jaxp.html#SourceValidator). You can feed it your XML file and it will validate it.

As for Xerces-C, I haven't used it myself, but I know it does not require all of the Visual C++, all it needs is *runtime* files. These can be downloaded separately from Microsoft. There seems to be a sample application which does what you need - see [StdInParse](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/stdinparse-3.html)