# Is XMLLint for Windows in active development?

Tags: xml, batch-processing, xsd-validation, xmllint

I have a project to validate XML files according to XSD specs:

- It should run from Windows command line
- Validation errors should be saved to a file for later review

XMLLint looks like the perfect candidate. It does all of the above. However, this particular branch (ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/win32/64bit/) hasn't been updated since 2015.

Given the age, is this safe to rely on for the next few years? If not, is there an alternative that meets the above requirements?

Comment: You can try [xcop](https://github.com/yegor256/xcop) instead (I'm a developer)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same question.  After some creative googling, I found the project is still active on GitLab.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2

Binaries for a variety of platforms are built using the GitLab CI pipeline.  For example, I was able to get a current Windows build here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/jobs/1236352/artifacts/browse

Download the ZIP.  The .exe files are in the `bin` folder.  Linux binaries are available as well from the corresponding build jobs.