# XML DTD/Schema validation in Maven

Tags: xml, validation, maven-2, xsd, maven-plugin

How can I validate XML documents during a Maven build against a DTD or a XSD Schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [xml-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/index.html) that can check whether XML files are [matching an XML schema](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/examples/validate-schema.html) but I don't think it can generate reports.

Answer (score 5):

The [validate goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/validate-mojo.html) of the xml-maven-plugin will check for well-formedness and optionally validate against a schema. The build will fail if the validation fails.

The plugin does not produce any report, what would you want in a report out of interest? information about the invalid files?

Here is an example usage:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>validate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <validationSets>
        <validationSet>
          <dir>src/main/xml</dir>
          <systemId>src/main/xmlschema.xsd</systemId>
        </validationSet>
      </validationSets>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, validatation error reports will help point out posible errors in xml files like PMD or Findbug does for java code. I've noticed that many developers skip xml or jsp validation errors/warnings while working with project, what may cause potential runtime errors.

Comment: Agreed.  Not as useful to just fail the build, but to fail the build and print the schema validation error... now that is super-useful.  Especially if you only use IDEs when you need to debug something.

Comment: also see http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/examples/validate-schema.html and https://github.com/mojohaus/xml-maven-plugin/pull/52

Comment: Can someone help me, on how to include the files to be validated against the schema.

Comment: The example POM snippet illustrates usage, though description of _2 main parameters_ would be rounding up. What's the difference to answer already given by @Pascal Thivent?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [xml-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/usage.html) for some time (thanks to [Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527864/2799887) and [Rick Seller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527909/2799887) for introducing me to this), but had some problems with it.

I was validating an XML document. At some point we split the XML document in two files, both in their own subdirectory. At that point the xml-maven-plugin did not validate anything anymore because the file was moved, but also did not complain about it. Also personally I found the configuration not too intuitive and a bit hard to debug if it does not do you expect.

So for me I was happy to rediscover the [schemavalidate](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/schemavalidate.html) Ant task combined with the [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html). Did everything I needed and more.

In the example below I check that files are actually selected. Off course you can tailor this for your specific needs. As a bonus (tough a bit off topic) an example of how I grab the path of an xsd that is downloaded as a dependency.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId><version>1.8</version>
            <executions><execution>
                <id>validate-xml-document-files-against-schema</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <copy file="${maven.dependency.com.mycompany.some-schema.xsd.path}" tofile="${xml-validation-dir}/some-schema.xsd" />
                        <resourcecount property="xml.count">
                            <fileset dir="${xml-validation-dir}" includes="**/*.xml" />
                        </resourcecount>
                        <fail message="fileset does not match any xml file (use same fileset for actual validation)">
                            <condition><equals arg1="${xml.count}" arg2="0" /></condition>
                        </fail>
                        <echo message="validating ${xml.count} xml files against some-schema" />
                        <schemavalidate>
                            <schema namespace="http://mycompany.com/some-namespace" file="${xml-validation-dir}/some-schema.xsd" />
                            <fileset dir="${xml-validation-dir}" includes="**/*.xml" />
                        </schemavalidate>
                        <echo message="all ${xml.count} xml documents are valid" />
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </execution></executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-schema-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <type>xsd</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Granted, this does not really fit in the maven way of working, but it worked for me and maybe somebody else is helped by knowing this option.