# Notepad++ XmlTools Not Installing

Tags: notepad++

This is depressing - I have installed XMLTools and can see it in the menu - It has one sub menu which is "How To Use"

If I select that it says something like no libxml / libxslt - Google returns nothing

How can I install this plugin properly

Comment: 2019, still having this problem.  None of the solutions worked.

Comment: 2019, same here. Seems the problem is here again?

Comment: Windows 10 works a bit different:
C:\Users\<<uername>>\AppData\Local\Notepad++\plugins
There are folders for every plugin.
You have to add a Folder XMLTools and put the XMLTools.dll in there. Sure the ext libs go further in the Notpadd++ main dir:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\

Comment: Notepad ++ is actually a programming tool so I think is not correct to close the question ....

Comment: I tried everything suggested and can't get XmlTools to run. I just ended up using **XPatherizerNPP**.

Comment: For anyone having this problem in 2019, **you may need to upgrade Notepad++** to resolve the issue. According to the forums, there is an apparent incompatibility between XML Tools 2.4.11 and Notepad++ 7.5.9: [https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/16957/xml-tools-will-not-work-after-update-from-plugin-manager/2](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/16957/xml-tools-will-not-work-after-update-from-plugin-manager/2). In my case, upgrading to Notepad++ 7.6.3 and reinstalling XmlTools via the plugin manager worked like a charm.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Hey, just had the same issue.

You need to download [ext_libs.zip](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_npp-plugins/downloads/XML%20Tools/Xml%20Tools%202.3.1%20r764%20Unicode%20Beta1/ext_libs.zip/), and extract the contents to where you have installed the Notepadd++.

Something like

> C:\Program Files\Notepad++

Then restart Notepad++, and this should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: With the latest release (April 2012), these libs are bundled in the main plugin .zip file.

Comment: This is not working for me. No errors but I can't see it the Plugins menu.

Comment: Now get this error: "This Ansi Plugin is not compatible with your Unicode Notepad++.
This plugin is not compatible with current version of Notepad++."

Comment: Windows 10 works a bit different:
C:\Users\<<uername>>\AppData\Local\Notepad++\plugins
There are folders for every plugin.
You have to add a Folder XMLTools and put the XMLTools.dll in there. Sure the ext libs go further in the Notpadd++ main dir:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\

Comment: Nothing of this works for me.

Comment: In my case this did the trick: I completely uninstalled and re-installed (not an update from NP++ menu) the latest version 7.6.4 (64-bit). After that, I re-installed XMLTools plugin using Plugins Admin menu.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using windows vista+ please make sure you run Notepad++ as administrator before trying to install plugins.