# how to match two xml string?

Tags: java, xsd

I am getting some information in the form of XML.

Before using that xml I want to validate that all the information is in that XML.

For this purpose I will have a master copy of XML, against which i will match all the coming documents.

How can i do this?

Comment: Are you referring to the structure of the XML? In that case, you can use XSD validation.

Comment: yes In string message structure is of xml

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot of work, but you could use XPath depending on the size and structure of your xml. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp.

Also there is a really good starting tutorial here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html

And if you're willing to do validation through the use of your xsd (if there is one), look at ( [XML Schema (XSD) validation tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124865/xml-schema-xsd-validation-tool) )

Answer (score 0):

A common approach for validating xml is to define a *schema* (`xsd` or `dtd`). A parser can validate the input xml document against all constraints that are specified in the schema document.

This is a common way if you need to make sure, that certains elements are present and that certain values are within a specified value range.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following link to see how an xml can be validated against a dtd in java

http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/DOMValidateDTD.shtml