# XSD validation functionality from node.js?

Tags: xml, node.js, xsd

I am building a service which needs to validate XML files adhere to a given schema. In perusing the list of node modules at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules I see several XML parsing solutions but none of them, at first glance, appear to support XSD.

Are there other solutions out there I missed?  Alternatively I am considering implementing a node proxy to an external library's functionality.  The following [question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124865/xml-schema-xsd-validation-tool) has several good suggestions (Xerces and Xmllint being interesting) along these lines.  Would something else be preferable?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing XML validation through DTD's instead by calling the command line **xmllint** program.  I wasn't confident about the maturity of the XSD validation libraries I looked at as they seemed to be incomplete, for the most part.

Comment: can u tell me how you validated XML through DTD? I am facing a similar problem